# Keycloak as identy provider and TokenExchange error

Tags: keycloak, exchange-server

I have two keycloaks, one is accessing the other as an identity provider, when I try to do TokenExchange it gives the following error

```
"error_description": "identity provider is not linked, can only link to current user session",
"account-link-url": "https://myURL/auth/realms/Desenv/broker/keycloak-oidc/link?nonce=4cf016a3-8661-40f8-a4da-0bf5a816d45f&hash=fuecBsFEXg7wZMoUA2bNvyQFW-_xzpTxmXxczCVX0gQ&client_id=client_testeTokenExchange",
"error": "not_linked"
```

}
I can do TokenExchange  from one client to another within the same keycloak, but not to a keycloak outside.

TokenExchange with external keycloak as identy provider.